# Vue3 components interfere

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vite, laravel-mix-vue3

So im working on an existing laravel project with vue3, which recently got upgraded from vue2 to vue3. After upgrading i have the problem that components interfere with each other.

for example:

child component:

```
<input v-model="input" />

export default {
   name: 'inputField'
   data() {
      return {
         input: ''
      }
   }
}
```

parent:

```
<inputField />
<inputField />
```

When i use one of the input fields, it affects the input variable of both of them.

I have already tried changing from laravel-mix to vite, but that didnt seem to work. I have searched online but no one else seems to have this problem. Does anyone know why this is and how to fix it?

Comment: The problem requires [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. enough code and information to make the problem reproducible. If you can't narrow it down to specific code, a github repo could suffice.

Comment: Depends on the case. `key` may need to be specified if component structure is not static

Comment: With the given code, the problem is not reproduceable so I cannot give a satisfactory answer. Is the number of inputs static or are they dynamically rendered? Please try to provide code that can reproduce the problem. Also, maybe try wrapping your export in define component? 
export default defineComponent({
// stuff here
})